# Postgresql sql query convert time in second

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have `MySQL` DB and i am using following syntax to convert my `datetime` type in second

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) as time_sec, blah..blah..
```

But now i have other postgresql DB which has `timestamp with time zone` type so how do i convert that time in `second` with my select query?

`2018-04-18 18:27:48.96283+00` This is this format of timestamp in table which i want to convert in `seconds`

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`select extract(epoch from created_at) as time_sec from tsepok`

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4308e02892203a29029c3af2d4ad436c)*

[more docs here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html)